# Изменить view по позиции RecyclerView после завершения вызова startActivityForResult

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

У меня есть список `RecyclerView` где в итемах есть кнопка при нажатие которой я запускаю активность через `startActivityForResult`, в активности я спрашиваю пользователя что он хочет сделать с итемом, мне нужно после выбора действия пользователем изменить стиль отображения этого итема, но у меня не получается это сделать, так как управление я получаю тока в методе `onActivityResult`, как получить view нажатого элемента находясь "вне" метода обработки нажатия по кнопке в итеме?

Обновил, надеюсь так будет понятнее в чем проблема

Comment: Добавьте код или сформулируйте вопрос более конкретно так как не совсем понятно в чем проблема. Вообще из ребуса который вы предоставили я предпологаю что вам поможет Tag.

Comment: Обновил описание проблемы, так понятно о чем речь?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение простое, странно что я раньше не догадался.
Нужно было просто поменять свойство итема (в моем случае это был status) по завершении операции в активности через адаптер, а потом просто перерисовать `RecyclerView` а именно сообщить что были изменения, и в итоге `RecyclerView` сам перерисует все как надо исходя из свойств итемов. Главное прописать как отображать тот или другой итем в зависимости от свойств, а с этим проблем там нет.

Вот здесь описано как сообщить адаптеру что были внесены изменения:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30053610/best-way-to-update-data-with-a-recyclerview-adapter